# How to set the values for array-attributes in C# Model Class

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have an model class ( Json converted to C# Class) in which i have an array and its attributes.

Now the problem is i need to set the values for this array `atrributes` namely `fieldId` and `fieldValue` which is present in array called `optionalFields`.

Just to give an heads up i have written an constructor where i can initialize the variables which is is an direct shot but i tried few ways to to set an values for the array attributes but then i was literally wasting time.

### Below is the Json :

```
{
  "entityId": "1234",
  "inventoryId": "4567",
  "saleAccount": "SAA",
  "saleGroup": "SLL",
  "inventoryAccount": "IA1000",
  "workInProcess": 0,
  "isGlApplied": false,
  "optionalFields": [
    {
      "fieldId": "29",
      "fieldValue": "290"
    }
  ],

}
```

Below is the Model Class for the above json:

```
public class Acct_Det_Widget_Post_Insert_Json
{
    public string entityId { get; set; }
    public string inventoryId { get; set; }
    public string saleAccount { get; set; }
    public string saleGroup { get; set; }
    public string inventoryAccount { get; set; }
    public int workInProcess { get; set; }
    public bool isGlApplied { get; set; }
    public Optionalfield[] optionalFields { get; set; }

    public string vehicleId { get; set; }

    public Acct_Det_Widget_Post_Insert_Json()
    {
        this.entityId = "1234";
        this.inventoryId = "34521";
        this.saleAccount = "SAA";
        this.saleGroup = "SLL";
        this.inventoryAccount = "IA1000";
        this.workInProcess = 0;
        this.isGlApplied = false;             
    }

}

public class Optionalfield
{
    public string fieldid { get; set; }
    public string fieldvalue { get; set; }    

}
```

I can set the values for other fields but I am not able to set the values for this `OptionalField` array attributes.

Please kindly help me with issue at the earliest.

Comment: Have you tried straight JSON deserialization?  new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Acct_Det_Widget_Post_Insert_Json>("Your JSON string variable goes here");

Comment: What do you mean by "I am not able to set the values for..."? why? what have you tried? do you get any errors or exceptions?

Comment: I knew the part of JSON deserialization but as i am a new bee just started learning C#  and i was struck while setting up the values to array attrib`s

Comment: It was my miss that I did not initialize the array and the syntax from java to C# is bit different and started getting used to it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the value for an array, it first has to be initialized.

```
public Optionalfield[] optionalFields { get; set; } = new Optionalfield[1];
```

If you want to add more than 1 value, simply change 1 to whatever you need.

Next, in your constructor, you can assign values as follows:

```
optionalFields[0] = new Optionalfield();
optionalFields[0].fieldid = "29";
optionalFields[0].fieldvalue = "290";
```

Notice that you have to create an instance of the class and assign it to a valid index of the array. In this case, the array is initialized with 1 element, you assign the instance to the first (0) element.

Comment: Hi Rik , Thanks a lot, it worked out and it was my miss i did not initialize the array. More Over i just started learning C# .